# detailed steps for bulk loading in HBase table

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am new to HBase. Can someone provide me a detailed example on how bulk loading can be done in a HBase table.

Say for example I have a customer file with 10 columns and 100K rows. I want to load the file in a HBase table.

I have created a HBase table which is managed by HIVE and tried to load the same using LOAD command, but it failed.

Looks like I have to insert the table from HBase only.

```
hive (Koushik)> CREATE TABLE hive_hbase_emp_sample(eid int, ename string, esal double) 
              > STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
              > WITH SERDEPROPERTIES 
              > ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,cfstr:enm,cfsal:esl")
              > TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name" = "hive_hbase_emp_sample");
OK
Time taken: 6.404 seconds

hive (Koushik)> load data local inpath '/home/hduser/sample_emp_file' into table hive_hbase_emp_sample;
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10101]: A non-native table cannot be used as target for LOAD
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot direcly use load for targeting a HbaseStorage Handler Non native table instead load data in a staging table and then insert into your Hbase table using select * from staging table